# script weird behaviour with ampersand at end

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script where I face a very strange problem.
My script is :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cd /scripts/my-scripts
echo "Getting data from database."
mysql -N -umyuser -pmypass -hdb.test.example.com  COLLEGE -e"select distinct id as myid from candidate_info where name = 'john' and id is not null  " > test_skus &
echo "DONE"
echo `wc -l test_skus`
```

It gives 0 as word count. But if I remove & at end of this :

```
mysql -N -umyuser -pmypass -hdb.test.example.com  COLLEGE -e"select distinct id as myid from candidate_info where name = 'john' and id is not null  " > test_skus &
```

It give results. What can be the reason ? Please help

Comment: the mysql query is done in background if you give &. see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line

Comment: @ymonad when i check this file why its empty then ?